# Can I assign two mice to two windows or have two pointers?

Tags: linux, mouse, touchpad, xinput, multi-pointer

I figured out how to put two pointers at the same time and control them with two mice (using xinput), but can I have them both assigned to a window? Since I can only have one window in focus I can't use both of the pointers properly because one will be on the focused window and the other one won't. I'm trying to play a LAN game with a friend and, if this is possible, we'll be able to play in split-screen. I have a second monitor available, but if possible I'd prefer it on one screen. I'm also trying to avoid emulation since I have an older PC with Ubuntu. I'm new to Linux so it would be nice if you could explain every step.

Comment: `I can't use both of the pointers properly` ... this is the same as `it's not working`... the statement does not contains any useful information ... please describe what you expect to happen and what you observed as happening

Comment: @jsotola your comment is redundant; it's pretty obvious that the OP wants to also use multiple keyboards each with its window in focus, kind of like it's described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multi-pointer_X). Unfortunately, I'm not able to test it now.

Comment: Can you write a question "How can I have two pointers at the same time and control them with two mice?" and then add an answer (You are allowed to do this. The site guidelines say that this is encouraged). This may be useful to people (me), and will help others in joining you in your quest to answer the 2nd part.

Comment: I thought I understood your question, but then I read it again: You say that you have it working but you don't. What is working what is not?

Comment: @mosvy I just tried what it says on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multi-pointer_X Two pointers, two keyboards, paired up, so that each keyboard has separate focus. It works. With 2 problems, the 2nd pointer is glitchy on my system. The window manager (KDE's plasma), does not know what to do to indicate focused window, only one is highlighted.